# Python: How do I create a reference to a reference?

Tags: python, reference, stdout

I am traditionally a Perl and C++ programmer, so apologies in advance if I am misunderstanding something trivial about Python!

I would like to create a reference to a reference.
Huh?  Ok.  All objects in Python are actually references to the real object.
So, how do I create a reference to this reference?

Why do I need/want this?  I am overriding sys.stdout and sys.stderr to create a logging library.  I would like a (second-level) reference to sys.stdout.

If I could create a reference to a reference, then I could create a generic logger class where the **init** function receives a reference to a file handle reference that will be overrided, e.g., sys.stdout or sys.stderr.  Currently, I must hard-code both values.

Cheers,
Kevin

Answer (score 6):

Easier done than said:

```
ostream = sys.stdout
print >> ostream, 'hi mom!'
ostream = sys.stderr
print >> ostream, 'hi mom!'
ostream = open('mylog.txt', 'a')
...
```

And look at the standard [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) when you have some more Python under your belt.

This answer was based on the presumption, from the level of the question, of what was really needed. The concept of a reference to a reference is not needed in Python, you can multiplex through a list or a dict if you want:

```
outputs = [sys.stderr, my_open_file_object_which_is_really_a_reference]
print >> outputs[0], 'hi dad!'
outputs = {'terminal': sys.stderr, 'logfile': file_object}
print >> outputs['logfile'], 'goodbye world!'
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create references to references in python. You can however override the `stderr` and `stdout` files with custom classes with `write` etc methods to allow your own logging systems:

```
import sys

class MyLogger:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # forward e.g. flush() calls to the original file
        return getattr(self.f, name)

    def write(self, data):
        # log the data here!
        # ...

        # And write to the original file
        self.f.write(data)

sys.stdout = MyLogger(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = MyLogger(sys.stderr)
```

Comment: The face that [sys.stdout = MyLogger(sys.stdout)] cannot be made generic is proof that Python is missing something.  Still, I like everything else I see.

Fortunately, there are only two file handles to override.  I can 'afford' to repeat twice =)

Thanks for the advice.  This solution most closely fits my original need.

Comment: Oh, also.  Great tip with \__getattr__.  I will add.

Comment: I've overriden the `stdout` and `stderr`, but it is possible to replace them with any object/class which has the method `write` (such as an alternative file, so `sys.stdout = open('mylog', 'wb')` will work.) I don't think it's limited at all - it's just a different language with a different philosophy behind it - references to objects I think go against the python philosophy (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), though I'm sure it fits with perl's "expressive" model which has it's own advantages and disadvantages :-P

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, there is no true "references of references" in python, but there are ways of getting nearly the same effect:

```
>>> reference1 = "Some Data"
>>> reference2 = (reference1,)
>>> def f(data):
    print data

>>> f(reference2)
('Some Data',)
>>> f(*reference2)
Some Data
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. Pass the desired attribute as a string and use `getattr()` and `setattr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is already a [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module, so you probably should just use that. Secondly, while there is no such thing as a reference to a reference, you can achieve that indirection via a wrapper or function. For example, if you were to create a getter and setter function for assigning the object, like:

```
 class StdOutWrapper(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.original = sys.stdout

      @property
      def value(self):
          return sys.stdout

      @value.setter
      def value(self,val):
          sys.stdout = val
```

You could then pass an instance of this object to your logger to assign/dereference sys.stdout.

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that I must hard-code sys.stdout.  This class cannot be created generically.

Comment: @KCArpe, yeah, that is correct. I was trying to save coding for whatever made use of the wrapper... the wrapper, itself, would have to be written both for sys.stdout and sys.stdin.